# How to abort loading component in Loader?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, loader, qqmlcomponent

I have a `Loader` object that loads some very heavy components. Some event arrives in the middle of the load that requires loading to stop and go back to empty the `Loader`. Is it possible?

Comment: Should be, with an `asyncronous` Loader. But this property fails me somehow. While the `UI` does not freeze as promised (`BusyIndicator` running) it is still completely unresponsive.

Comment: I have `asynchronous` set, but the problem is it destroys objects in  Loader while they are not finished loading, which causes warnings and errors.

Comment: What about setting `active` to false or setting `source`/`sourceComponent` to null?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong earlier, but uppon writing it once again, it works...

Comment: @folibis then it seems to never delete any objects and eventually runs out of memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Abort object creation**

As documented by Qt, three methods exists to unload/abort an object instantiation:

1. Set [`Loader.active`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#active-prop) to `false`
2. Set [`Loader.source`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#source-prop) to an empty string
3. Set [`Loader.sourceComponent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop) to `undefined`

**Asynchronous behaviour**

To be able to change these properties during loading, [`Loader.asynchronous`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#asynchronous-prop) should be `true`, otherwise the GUI thread is busy with loading the object. You also need to [`QQmlIncubationController`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlincubationcontroller.html) for your [`QQmlEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#setIncubationController) to control the idle time used for object incubation. Without such a controller `Loader.asynchronous` does not have any effect. Note that [`QQmlApplicationEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html#details) automatically installs a default controller if the scene contains a `QQuickWindow`.

**Bugs**

Up to the last tested Qt version (Qt 5.8.0, 5.9.0 beta), a severe memory leaks exist when aborting an unfinished object incubation (at least in certain cases, including the example in the answer of derM) resulting in a fast memory usage increase for large components. A [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60188) is created including a proposed solution.

According to the bug report, this should be fixed in Qt version 5.15 (not tested).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your issu is, with those *objects that are destroyed before the loader finishs*, but maybe the issue is there? If not, this should work:
If it does not help, please add some code to your question, that reproduces your problem.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 450

    Button {
        text: (complexLoader.active ? 'Loading' : 'Unloading')
        onClicked: complexLoader.active = !complexLoader.active
    }

    Loader {
        id: complexLoader
        y: 50
        width: 400
        height: 400
        source: 'ComplexComponent.qml'
        asynchronous: true
        active: false
        // visible: status === 1
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        anchors.fill: complexLoader
        running: complexLoader.status === 2
        visible: running
    }
}
```

**ComplexComponent.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400
    height: 400
    Grid {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 50
        columns: 50
        Repeater {
            model: parent.rows * parent.columns
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: root.width / grid.columns
                height: root.height / grid.rows
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(index),
                               Math.random(index),
                               Math.random(index),
                               Math.random(index))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you keep clicking button very fast, it never frees memory allocated for previous objects and eventually causes bad_alloc.

Comment: How often did you click with my `ComplexComponent`? :D I opted for a timer *clicking* every 200 or 500 ms, and did that for multiple minutes. But yes, the memory increases over time...

Comment: I set the timer to 200, but increased the number of rows and columns to 200. It grows memory very fast and crashes.

Comment: For 200x200, I do not see any memory increase (constant ~200MB). For smaller size (50x50), I do so see an increase, but this can be avoided by calling `gc` (i.e. garbage collection) manually after unloading. Except for the first time, `button.clicked()` takes a lot of time (up to 6s for 200x200), the GUI freezes, and the file is not loaded asynchronously (`Loader.Status` never becomes `Loader.Loading`). Tested on Qt 5.8, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @m7913d : Interesting that this happens to you. At the beginning I had exactly the same problem (well, actually the GUI-thread it self seemd to work, so the BusyIndicato if I remember it right, kept spinning, but the `Button` was indicated as `down` the whole time, and it was unloaded only after the loading was completed. Then I wanted to post this as an example that *does not work* when it suddenly worked. Tried it on several machines (Linux and Windows) by now, and it works for me :D

Comment: The above results were for using `QQuickWidget`. I switched to `QQmlApplicationEngine` (which creates a `QQmlIncubationController` automatically if the scene contains a `QQuickWindow`) and now `asynchronous` and aborting works, but memory leaks seem to occur. `gc` doesn't work anymore to clean up memory.

Comment: @m7913d I'm on Windows, calling `gc` does basically nothing (I use `QQmlApplicationEngine`).

Comment: This definitely seems to be a Qt bug. Can I use your example to fill in a bug report?

Comment: I submitted a [bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60188) including a possible solution.

Comment: @m7913d I'll write a support request when I get to my work laptop, maybe it'll get resolved faster.

Comment: Check whether calling `gc()` 3-4 times in a row has an effect on memory  usage. One rarely suffices, but 3-4 seem to squeeze as much garbage out as possible.

Comment: @dtech no effect.